# Are the limiting points of a double Droste effect the fixed points of some map?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cantor-set

Suppose $X$ is a complete bounded metric space, and we have two contractive self-embeddings $f, g : X \to X$ onto closed, disjoint subsets. Is there a natural way of assigning to the triple $(X, f, g)$ a map $h : X \to X$ such that the fixed points of $h$ are homeomorphic to the Cantor set?

I was inspired by consideration of a "double Droste effect," like [here](https://derpicdn.net/img/2019/4/21/2019209/large.png). In the case of a single Droste, the "limiting point" of the diagram is plainly the fixed point of the contractive map. However, in the case of a double Droste, the only way I can seem to describe the points is as the $2^\mathbb{N}$ points arising from the following: Let $s$ be a sequence in the set $\{f, g\}$, and $x \in X$. Then the limit

$$x, ~~~~~s(0)(x), ~~~~~s(0) \circ s(1) (x), ~~~~~s(0) \circ s(1) \circ s(2)(x), ~~~~~...~~\to ~~x_s$$

exists, is independent of $x$, and $s \mapsto x_s$ is injective with image subspatially homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

I suppose I don't have any deeper reason to assume there's a description of the points as fixed points, but perhaps I'm missing a nice construction.

Comment: Is there a map $h$ that you have in mind for a case like the pair of maps on $[0,1]$ given by $x/3$ and $x/3+2/3$, where you would get the usual Cantor set? It kind of seems like you're wanting to generalize something that might not be there in any natural way. (Though Eric Wofsey's answer is a very good idea for what you might *really* want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the natural "fixed-points" description is in terms of sets, not points.  In particular, let $Y$ be the set of nonempty compact subsets of $X$, equipped with the Hausdorff metric (which is complete since $X$ is complete).  There is then a map $h:Y\to Y$ given by $h(A)=f(A)\cup g(A)$, which is easily seen to be a contraction since $f$ and $g$ are.  The unique fixed point of this map $h$ is then exactly the Cantor set you describe.

Comment: Yes, this is as close to an answer as I could hope, seeing as I rather doubted my formulation of the question had an affirmative answer.